# Dataframe python reshape some values from horizontal to vertical

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 92 columns and 13 rows Dataframe where each row corresponds to one poker hand. Column (not all) names and values look like this:

```
'Soft','Hand_ID','Table_Size', 'Blinds', 'Day', 'No_of_players', 'Seat_1','Seat_2','Seat_3', 'Seat_4', 'Seat_5', 'Seat_6'
PokerStars  172109655423    6-max   €0.50/€1.00 2017/06/22  4   KO  fasolakia14 Johnii141   bogec   0   0
PokerStars  143736274858    6-max   £0.25/£0.50 2015/11/13  6   Racushniak  koluha1000  Bantina DMIGNN  Johnii141   vor4mohs
```

I need to reshape columns: 'Seat_1','Seat_2','Seat_3', 'Seat_4', 'Seat_5', 'Seat_6' to vertical.
Output shoud look like this:
[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to use pd.melt. Didnt see this beacuse of many columns in whole DataFrame.
Code can look like this:
    df_Seats = pd.melt(df, id_vars = ['Hand_ID','Soft','Table_Size', 'Blinds', 'Day', 'No_of_players','Pot', 'Rake'],
                    value_vars = ['Seat_1', 'Seat_2', 'Seat_3', 'Seat_4', 'Seat_5', 'Seat_6'],
                    var_name = 'Seats_var', value_name = 'Seats')

```
df_Seats = df_Seats.drop('Seats_var', 1)
```

Output looks:
http://prntscr.com/mrzu3z
but still dont know how to solve that values for Hand_Id, Soft etc are repeated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want to use `pd.melt`, assuming you have a pandas.DataFrame I advise using some simpler solution like this.

```
>>> df
Soft    Hand_ID Table_Size  Blinds  Day No_of_players   Seat_1  Seat_2  Seat_3  Seat_4  Seat_5  Seat_6
PokerStars  172109655423    6-max   €0.50/€1.00 2017/06/22  4   KO  fasolakia14 Johnii141   bogec   0   0
PokerStars  143736274858    6-max   £0.25/£0.50 2015/11/13  6   Racushniak  koluha1000  Bantina DMIGNN  Johnii141   vor4mohs
```

Just add your seat columns in one single column

```
>>> df['Seats'] = df['Seat_1'] + " " + df['Seat_2'] + " " + df['Seat_3'] + " " + df['Seat_4'] + " " + df['Seat_5'] + " " + df['Seat_6']
>>> df.drop(['Seat_1', 'Seat_2', 'Seat_3', 'Seat_4', 'Seat_5', 'Seat_6'], axis=1)
```

And you will have desired output

```
Soft    Hand_ID Table_Size  Blinds  Day No_of_players   Seats
PokerStars  172109655423    6-max   €0.50/€1.00 2017/06/22  4   KO fasolakia14 Johnii141 bogec 0 0
PokerStars  143736274858    6-max   £0.25/£0.50 2015/11/13  6   Racushniak koluha1000 Bantina DMIGNN Johnii141...
```

Comment: Ok, but i need this nicknames to be saved vertical for each hand.